# Подскажите как реализовать правильно анимацию сворачивания layout и toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с фрагментом. Вот так выглядит мой фрагмент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача у меня такая когда юзер открывает клавиатуру для ввода текста в поля в `scrollView` то часть вью элементов под номером 1 должны свернуться(анимированно) и когда клавиатура прячется то развернуться.

Я не совсем могу понять как привязать toolbar который в активити и остальные вью элементы которые во фрагменте и свернуть их , а потом развернуть...

Подскажите куда смотреть

Comment: Легче наверное будет сделать свой тулбар во фрагменте и работать уже с ним.

Comment: @eugeneek Хмм я не подумал об этом. Не показывать тулбар из активити и открывать тулбар из фрагмента, так? Но а насчет collapse эффекта?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [CoordinatorLayout](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/). Может вам подойдёт. Правда с клавиатурой это связать будет не просто. Вообще в андроид работать с клавиатурой неудобно, так что придётся подумать в любом случае.